# WPF patterns: Items and ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, design-patterns

Well I'm designing a Custom WPF control - fore the sake of learning - that display logs message in a similar way Visual Studio does. I want to allow the user add messages by adding message istances to an `Items` collection, or by binding to an `ItemSource`. I think this is a well established pattern in many wpf controls, but I have no Idea on how achieve it. I know I can obtain the same result by adding a listview as a part of my control, but the project goal is learning, so I prefer avoid that solution. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a [read](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/15/itemscontrol-a-is-for-abundance/) around the `ItemsControl`, your custom control can inherit from an `ItemsControl`, or a derivative of it. If you create an [`ObservableCollection`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ObservableCollection.aspx) containing your items and bind that to your `ItemsSource`, then your list will be automatically updated. You can [style](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/) the `ItemTemplate` and `Template` to give the list a different look and feel.

There's loads of info [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

Comment: interesting link too. Thanks.